# How to identify android product without region/carrier specific model number

Tags: android

I know I can read these values from Android device to identify a
specific model.

```
Build.MODEL
Build.MANUFACTURER
Build.PRODUCT
```

But the same product will have different value combinations
for different regions and carriers.

For example, Samsung Galaxy S5 has different Build.MODEL due
to different carrier and regions, there could be 10~20 such different
models numbers (can be found in Google Play Store), 
even they are all the same product: Galaxy S5.

Is there a easy way to identify Galaxy S5 without comparing
model number to all those 10~20 known model numbers?

Comment: are you sure these are exactly identical? I don't think they are, there are differences from a carrier to another.